# i want to use pillow module but

Tags: heroku, python-imaging-library

2020-08-05T11:18:47.632502+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 653, in load_extension
2020-08-05T11:18:47.632862+00:00 app[worker.1]:     self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
2020-08-05T11:18:47.632903+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 599, in _load_from_module_spec
2020-08-05T11:18:47.633218+00:00 app[worker.1]:     raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e
2020-08-05T11:18:47.633309+00:00 app[worker.1]: discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.DPB' raised an error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Pillow'
2020-08-05T11:18:47.713878+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1

in pip list it shows
image v1.5.32
Pillow v7.2.0

what is the issue?

code:
from Pillow import Image

Comment: Share your `requirements.txt` as well as the source code where you are importing `Pillow`.

Comment: @TinNguyen 
[requirements.txt](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/680017863070973995/740533369934446622/Screenshot_194.png)  and  [code](https://mystb.in/GreensboroPapuaRacing.python)

Comment: Discord cdn is blocked here. Use a pastebin.

Comment: @TinNguyen ok bin >> [requirements.txt](https://mystb.in/WithdrawalFeaturingExecuted.apache)

Comment: I assume it's running locally. Do `python -m pip freeze > requirements.txt` and commit that updated requirements.txt to git.

Comment: i did python -m pip freeze > requirements.txt in run_console of my app and it shows nothing ... and i use github to deploy  so  how/when to commit . i m confused what to do now :( @TinNguyen

Comment: @TinNguyen you have discord ? here i m new so it looks awkward . please help me there  ... my id : ashu#9108

Comment: I'm at work. As I said Discord CDN is blocked. You need to get the project to run locally first. Only then should you test if it works in production. Your `requirements.txt` looks bad and you need to generate that with `python -m pip freeze > requirements.txt`.